# Using FileUpload on a modal popup and handling postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms, updatepanel

I'm stuck in a catch-22 situation...

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms application, that uses model popups (using the Ajax Control Toolkit's `ModalPopupExtender` component) to get inputs from user.

One screen is used to add new members, or edit existing member's records. These records include a picture of the member, which I'm uploading using a standard ASP.NET `FileUpload` control.

That create/edit screen is wrapped in an `UpdatePanel` so that when I pop up the overlay, I can fill in the textboxes with existing values (when editing an existing member).

Since the popup uses an `UpdatePanel`, I had to define an explicit `PostBackTrigger` so that my `Save` button will actually cause a complete postback and so that I'm able to read up the bytes of the picture uploaded in the `FileUpload` control.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlCreateOrEdit" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        .... asp.net controls here, including:
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadPic" runat="server" />
        ....
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="BtnSaveClicked" Text="Save" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If I don't define that `PostBackTrigger`, then my uploaded file can't be read out.

**BUT:** once I define that postback trigger, now I cannot do my validation anymore, since if I do my validation in the `btnSaveClicked` method and it fails (something is missing for instance), I can detect that - but I can't respond to it anymore, since the popup will be closed no matter what I've tried so far....

```
protected void BtnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // do my validation - if something is amiss, don't go any further
   if (!IsValid()) {
      return;
   }

   // read back the data
   // hide the modal popup form
   // call an event handler to process the inputs
}
```

So now I'm stuck:

- if I omit the post back trigger, my validation works nicely - if something is wrong, it's flagged and shown on the popup form, and the popup isn't closed
  ==> **BUT** in that case I cannot read out the bytes of the uploaded picture..... (`uploadPic.HasFile` is always `false`)
- if I put in the post back trigger, my file upload works nicely, I can read out my bytes no problem
  ==> **BUT** now, my validation - while detecting something's amiss - cannot show the error since the popup form is being closed by the full postback....

Is there any way to get **BOTH** - the bytes in the `FileUpload` control, **AND** the popup staying open if validation fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `AsyncFileUpload` component from the Ajax Control Toolkit - this works nicely on an `UpdatePanel` and satisfies all my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This popup will give you complete control with out any post back issues.
you can see this in action here: http://atldunia.com/youtube/Zpopup.aspx 
you can also download the code.